# Please explain VBA code elements, attribute types with different color and shape

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone explain the meaning of different elements,attributes in VBA code. While writing some procedures i have noticed some attributes with different color and shapes. Please refer to below snapshot for details. 
E.g.

```
row_Counter = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=Formulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False).Row
```

So while writing LookAt or any other attributes takes different values such as xlPart, ABS and many more to choose from. i found every values have some specific color and shapes. What does those signifies ?

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different icons represent different types of objects you can append.

The green rubber icon (e.g. ABS) represents a function.

The hand pointing on a spreadhseet (e.g. Active Cell) represents a property.

The black equal sign in a grey rectangle (e.g. BackstageGroupStyleError) represents a constant. - Not in your screenshot but might appear.

In general it helps the user to see, whether he is about to enter a function or just read a constant, as functions, properties and constants have different settings/uses.

If you like to know more about the issue press "F2" while in the Visual Editor and the "Object Browser" whith all available VBA objects will open.

Best regards
seulberg1

Comment: Seulberg, Thank you for the explanation. F2 part was really helpful.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.100).aspx) are some more symbols. These are for visual basic but cover what I saw in the object browser. Except there is a symbol for default member that is not in the table...

Answer (score 0):

Press F1 on `find` and it will explain what they are, then you can prefix so, say `xlLookAt.` `xlLookIn.`  etc, they are enumerations.   A bit of research is what is needed.  `XlLookAt.xlPart=2` `XlLookAt.xlWhole=1` for example, like `vbMonday` etc.